# How to use the variable data that is coming from the subscribe in outside in the method of calling the API in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, api, angular8

In my angular application I have called the API in service and subscribed that data in component but I am unable to use that variable (inside the subscribe) in outside.

**.service.ts**

```
dronedetails():Observable<object>{
  let httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('token')
    })
  };
 
    return this.http.get(environment.apiUrl +'/api/data/json', httpOptions)
```

And I have subscribed that data in component

**.component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {

this.ds.dronedetails()
       .subscribe((drones)=>{
         this.drones = drones;

      console.log('obj',drones);
       },
       err=>{
        console.log("Error",err)
      }
       );
//If I want to use that drone details it is not taking that drone details

var latlngs = this.drones.drone1.Drone.latlong;
    var droneid = this.drones.drone1.Drone.Droneid;

}
```

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Do you have any error? What's your problem clearly? Your code looks OK.

Comment: yes,It is not taking the drones object in outside the subscription in component.

Comment: Do you have it in the sbscribe? What's the output of this `console.log('obj',drones);`? where do you define ` this.drones`. is it `public` or `private` property? Please complete your code. Both `Component` & `Service`. Check the response of `http` request first. Check `console` if there is any error or not? may be you didn't inject your service properly. It should be more clear that we can help you. It's unclear question

Comment: I am getting the object as drone1:
Drone: {Droneid: 1001, company: "DJI", model: "DJIV2",latlong:[array values]}.and if use the drone details after subscribe method it is showing the error like: Cannot read property 'Drone' of undefined.Can you please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the subscription is executed asynchronously which means that whatever you wanna do with the information you get from your api, you must do it inside the subscription. If you try to access `this.drones` just after the call to your api, your variable won't be defined yet

Comment: From the API only I have subscribed the data.Now I want to use the drones data is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can access the drone's data but only inside the subscription, you can manipulate your data with some other functions but you must call them inside your subscription. You can also use the data inside your template and it will display them once your variable is defined